# How to avoid "Variable j written into, but never read" in Swift?

Tags: swift3, swift-playground

I am using variable j to print its final value inside a defer block as shown below:

```
func justForFun()
{    
   defer {let x = j; print("\(x)")}
   var j = 0
   for i in 1...5
   {
       print("\(i)")
       j = i*2;
   }
}
justForFun()
```

So, the variable **j** is indeed read and printed inside the defer block. Still, PlayGround displays the warning that **variable j is written, but never read**. Is there a way to enlighten the compiler and to rid this warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning disappears if the variable declaration is moved above the `defer`.

```
$ cat d.swift 
func justForFun() {    
   var j = 0
   defer {let x = j; print("\(x)")}
   for i in 1...5 {
       print("\(i)")
       j = i*2;
   }
}
justForFun()

$ swift d.swift 
1 
2
3
4
5
10
```

While this doesn't explain *why* the warning appears, it does answer how you can make the warning go away.

As far as enlightening the compiler, I don't think you can do that. You might want to file and issue at swift.org; see [this page](https://swift.org/contributing/#reporting-bugs) for how to report a bug. It seems the static flow checker is not looking at `defer` statements, which I believe it should. Good find.

Comment: Is there a way to give a 'half-tick" mark to this answer, as it has answered the first part of my question? I would like to convert this to full tick if there is no other answer or if my second part of question is a known bug in Swift 3.

Comment: That's a good question. Don't upvote if it doesn't help you. You can wait for an answer or try the Swift forums or post a bug report and see what the developers say. Looks like a bug to me, but I can't tell you for sure.

Comment: I have waited for four days and filed this as a bug in the site indicated by you. I am fully convinced of giving the full tick mark to you.

Comment: I hope you find an answer. It's an interesting case. If Swift would have adopted the rule that said the scope of a local extends from the point of declaration to the end of the block, then I would have expected a compiler error saying that the use of `j` in the `defer` block was not in scope. The fact that a warning occurs is pretty strange.

Answer (score 1):

## Workaround

Adding an anonymous assignment, `_ =` , eliminates the warning:

```
// Swift 3.0
func justForFun()
{
  defer {let x = j; print("\(x)")}
  var j = 0

  // anonymous assignment:
  _ = j
  for i in 1...5
  {
    print("\(i)")
    j = i*2;
  }
}

justForFun()
```

Comment: My apologies. I am not able to comprehend your comment "As for.... stones". Please paraphrase.

Comment: While I don't default to being flippant in SO, it seemed to me that when the OP named his function `justForFun()`, he was setting a lighthearted tone. But lighthearted != confusing. I've removed that line.